# Android Custom Tabview Layout

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to make a custom tabview desin, By default he tabviews in android are inline, But I want them to like the the image below. Any clues on how we can achieve this design without loosing native features of tabviews?

I want to create tabviews like the design as shown in image below.

[image]

Is is possible to make tabviews like this in Android with Java and XML ?

Comment: I want to be sure - do you want to chive this view(in the image)

Comment: Yes, I want to make the above tablayout design

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use all kind of different layouts for this but the best option considering different screen sizes would be to use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout).

**Here is an example:**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Fragments.MenusDesign.ExpandableCategoriesMenu.ExpandableCategoriesMenu"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:hint="Personal info"
    android:text="Personal info"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/switch1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/switch1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Full name"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline5" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.7" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline4" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But if i start to make custom layouts then i will lose all the native functionalities like slide or swipe between fragments, fragments lifecycle etc

Is there a way to do this using the native components ?

Comment: You are not so clear - ConstraintLayout is native, it's not something special. can you explain why this cant be your fragment layout(I don't see it affect anything but how the layout will look like )?